# Open a post ID on Facebook app with Intent

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-studio, mobile

I have installed 2 Facebook app on my android device (com.facebook.katana, com.facebook.katanb).
Now, I want to open a post id on com.facebook.katanb package.
I tried as below:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://post/2377836809193490"));
            intent.setPackage("com.facebook.katanb");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
```

However, It's not worked.
Is there anyone who could help me?